# Import Data to cassandra and create the Primary Key

Tags: import, copy, cassandra

I've got some csv data to import to cassandra. This could work with the copy-command. The Problem is, that the csv doesn't serve a unique ID for the data so I need to create a timeuuid on import.

Is it possible to do this via copy-command or did I need to write a external script for importing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a quick script to do it, the copy command can really only handle small amounts of data anyway. Try the [new python driver](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/python-driver/1.0/webhelp/index.html). I find it quite fast to setup loading scripts with, especially if you need any sort of minor modifications of the data before being loaded.

If you have a really big set of data [bulk-loading](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html) is still the way to go.

Comment: I solved it via a small ruby-script and pumped it agains my api. Not realy fast but enough for my case. THX